Spring open feign set custom header using baggage (or trace)
I'm developing a spring boot 3 application that must invoke some remote http services.
Inside the application there is a job executing some business logic.
In the business logic there is also the remote services invocation.
I'm trying to find a way to correlate the different http requests i.e. if the business logic is working on a specific object with an Id 123456 I'd like to set a custom header say x-object-id, with value 123456. The business logic does not interact directly with the different feign clients, but it uses some adapter.
In order to achieve this I added the following dependencies:
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
      <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>

I added a custom baggage field to my configuration
    @Bean
    BaggageField userIdField() {
        return BaggageField.create("baggage1");
    }

I wrote a test with the following line :
try (BaggageInScope scope = this.tracer.createBaggageInScope("baggage1", "value1")) {

where I invoke the business logic, but I do not see any header baggage1 sent by the feing client.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is using baggage the correct way to inject custom headers in feign?

To correlate the HTTP requests with a custom header, you can use a combination of Spring Boot's built-in features and some clever design. Here's a suggested approach:
1. Introduce a ThreadLocal context
Create a ThreadLocal context to store the object ID (123456) that you want to correlate with the HTTP requests. This will allow you to access the object ID from within the Feign clients.
Create a CorrelationContext class:
java
public class CorrelationContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> objectId = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        CorrelationContext.objectId.set(objectId);
    }

    public static String getObjectId() {
        return CorrelationContext.objectId.get();
    }
}

2. Set the object ID in the business logic
In your business logic, set the object ID using the CorrelationContext before invoking the adapters that will eventually call the Feign clients:
java
public class BusinessLogic {
    public void processObject(Object object) {
        CorrelationContext.setObjectId(object.getId().toString());
        // Call adapters that will invoke Feign clients
        adapter.doSomething();
    }
}

3. Create a Feign client configuration
Create a Feign client configuration that will add the custom header to each HTTP request. You can use a RequestInterceptor to achieve this:
@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor correlationRequestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> {
            String objectId = CorrelationContext.getObjectId();
            if (objectId!= null) {
                requestTemplate.header("X-Object-Id", objectId);
            }
        };
    }
}

4. Configure Feign clients to use the custom configuration
Update your Feign client configurations to use the custom FeignClientConfig:
@FeignClient(name = "my-feign-client", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {
    // Feign client methods
}

5. Use the Feign clients through adapters
In your adapters, use the Feign clients to make HTTP requests. The custom header will be automatically added to each request:
public class MyAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MyFeignClient myFeignClient;

    public void doSomething() {
        myFeignClient.makeHttpRequest();
    }
}

By following these steps, you should be able to correlate the HTTP requests with the custom X-Object-Id header. When the business logic sets the object ID using the CorrelationContext, it will be available to the Feign clients through the RequestInterceptor, which will add the custom header to each HTTP request.
Remember to remove the object ID from the CorrelationContext when the business logic is finished processing the object, to avoid leaking the context to other threads. You can do this by calling CorrelationContext.setObjectId(null) after processing the object.

thank you, I was thinking about using a thread local, but I'm looking for a more "transparent" solution. I have several feign clients and I'd like to avoid to specify a custom config class for each of them.
